# XMLHttpRequest: String a HTML

Tags: javascript, html, promesas

Quiero hacer una petición a un servidor, que el mismo me devuelve el html completo. Lo obtengo como un string, pero me gustaria transformarlo a HTML para luego manipular el DOM del mismo.

```
var URL_PATH = 'https://www.web.com.pe/web/web/web.jsp';
var method = "GET";
var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();

peticion.open(method, URL_PATH, true);

var promesa = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    peticion.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
        if(peticion.readyState === 4){
            resolve(peticion);
        }
    })

    peticion.addEventListener('error', function(){
        reject(peticion);
    });
});

peticion.send();

promesa.then(function(request){
    console.log(request.responseText);
    var textHtml = request.responseText;
    var html = document.createElement('html');
    html.innerHTML = textHtml;
    var email = html.getElementById('IdQueQuerioManipular');
}, function(request){
    console.log('rechazo: ', request);
});
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, solo te falta un .append(html), para agregarlo a algún lugar de tu DOM.

Comment: Tienes algún error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dije en los comentarios, solo falta un `.append(html)` a algún lugar de tu DOM. Una vez hecho esto, tienes libertad para manipularlo como quieras.

```js
var URL_PATH = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS';
var method = "GET";
var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();

peticion.open(method, URL_PATH, true);

var promesa = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  peticion.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (peticion.readyState === 4) {
      resolve(peticion);
    }
  })

  peticion.addEventListener('error', function() {
    reject(peticion);
  });
});

peticion.send();

promesa.then(function(request) {
  var textHtml = request.responseText;
  var html = document.createElement('html');
  html.innerHTML = textHtml;
  var contenido = document.getElementById('contenido');
  contenido.append(html);// <-- Aqui el append

  //Aquí ya tenemos acceso al DOM que fuimos a buscar
  const titulo = document.getElementsByClassName("document-title")[0].innerText;

  console.log("El título de la página es: " + titulo);

}, function(request) {
  console.log('rechazo: ', request);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="contenido">
</div>
</div>
```

**Cuidado**: La página que estoy consultando (developer.mozilla.org) tiene actualmente un allow origin *, si esto cambia en el futuro va a tirar un error de CORS.